# Is there any way to use a string as a comparison operator in Javascript or with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to use a string as a comparison operator (such as ==, >, <, <=, >=, <>, !=, !<, !>)

Essentially, I'm parsing a string that looks like this...

```
var my_string = "id==2";
```

I then convert this string into an array that ends up looking like this...

```
var my_array = ["id", "==", "2"];
```

I then have an object like so...

```
var my_obj = { id: 2, name: "My Object" };
```

I want to be able to grab the string version of my comparison operator from my_array at index 1 and use it as a comparison operator in a similar fashion to this...

```
if(my_array[0] in my_obj)
{
    var object_value = my_obj[my_array[0]];
    var is_true = PreformComparison(my_array[2], my_array[1], object_value);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't want slow tricks like `eval`, the best solution would be to have a map of functions:

```
var funs = {
    '==':function(a,b){ return a==b },
    '>':function(a,b){ return a>b },
    ...
}
```

You then can call it like this:

```
var is_true = funs[my_array[1]](object_value, my_array[2]);
```

Comment: Yah I assumed that the would more than likely be the only reasonable solution... Just wanted to make sure before I made it.